# two methods of a class constructor

Tags: java

I have a main class called User implemented as follows

```
package edu.uoc.dpoo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class User {

   private String username;
   private String password;
   private String fullName;

   private Platform platform;

   private List<Message> inBox;
   private List<Message> outBox;


   public User(String username, String password, String fullName) {

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.fullName = fullName;

    inBox = new ArrayList<Message>();
    outBox = new ArrayList<Message>();
  }

    public User() {
       username="";
       password="";
       fullName="";
    }




public String getUserName() {
    return username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setUserName(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public void setFullName(String fullname) {
    this.fullName = fullname;
}


public boolean checkPassword(String password){

    if (password.equals(this.password)){

        return true;
    }else
    {
            return false;
            }        
}

public List<Message> getMessages() {
    return null;
}
public Organizer asOrganizer(){
      Organizer ObjetoO =  new Organizer(username,password,fullName);
    return  ObjetoO;
}



public Participant asParticipant(){
    Participant ObjetoP =  new Participant(username,password,fullName);
    return  ObjetoP;

}



public Message sendMessage(String to,String Subject,String message){
    return null;
}

public String toString () {
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean equals (Object o) {
    boolean prueba = false;

    if ((o != null) && (o instanceof User)) {
        User p = (User) o;
        if (this.username == null && this.password == null && this.fullName == null) {
            prueba = (p.username == null);
                            prueba = (p.password == null);
                            prueba = (p.fullName == null);
        }
        else {
            prueba =  this.username.equals(p.username);
                            prueba =  this.password.equals(p.password);
                            prueba =  this.fullName.equals(p.fullName);
        }
    }

    return prueba;
}

    public List<Competition> myCompetitions(){
        return null;
    }


 User(User u1) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}


}
```

And two classes that inherit from User that are Organizer and Participant implemented as follows

Organizer

```
package edu.uoc.dpoo;

import java.util.ArrayList;  
import java.util.List;

public class Organizer extends User {

    private List<Competition> competitions;



    public Organizer(String username, String password, String fullName) {
        super(username, password, fullName);
                competitions = new ArrayList<Competition>();

    }

    public boolean removeSubmission(Submission submission){
        return true;

    }

    public boolean sendMessage(Competition competition, String subject, String message){
        return true;

    }

    public Competition newCompetition(String tittle,float target){
        return null;

    }
    public void closeCompetition(Competition competition){

    }

}


   Participant 

    package edu.uoc.dpoo;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    public class Participant extends User {

    private List<Competition> competitions;
       private List<Submission> submission;



    public Participant(String username, String password, String fullName) {
        super(username, password, fullName);
                competitions = new ArrayList<Competition>();
                submission = new ArrayList<Submission>();
    }

    public Submission submitPrediction(Competition competition, float prediction){
        return null;
    }
    public List<Submission> getSubmissions(){
        return null;
    }

    void asParticipant(Submission aThis) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

}
```

I'm asked to implement the asOrganizer and asParticipant methods of the User class. 
 These methods must create an object of the specific class, and initialize the parent class with the data of the User object. To perform this task, you are prompted to implement the copy constructor of the User class.

I create the objects in the two methods that ask me but I should not do something well in the constructor because junit fails me

I add the junit that fails me

```
   @Test
    public void userCopyConstructor() {        
    Platform platform = new Platform();
    User u1=platform.registerUser(username1, password1, fullName1);

    // User is not NULL
    assertNotNull(u1);

    // Get a participant object from user object
    User u2 = new User(u1);        
    assertNotNull(u2);
    assertEquals(u1, u2);        
}
```

My problem comes at this point

```
   // Get a participant object from user object
    User u2 = new User(u1);        
    assertNotNull(u2);
    assertEquals(u1, u2);
```

Comment: "because junit fails me" -- Can you provide more details?

Comment: what exactly is the problem? How is this code related to it? please provide a [mcve]

Comment: this seems like a big violation of the open/closed principle... any time you'd want to add "another version" of user you'd need to create the class, and modify user to have an "asNewThing" impl?

Comment: `Organizer` and `Participant` extend `User`, but `User` needs to know about  `Organizer` and `Participant`.  This is a cyclic dependency and is a poor design.  There should probably be a Factory that takes a `User` and can create an `Organizer` or `Participant`.

Comment: @bradimus 
I just edited explaining my problem better

Comment: `User u2 = new User(u1);` -- You need to define a copy constructor `public User(User source){ ... `

Comment: @bradimus 
That's my problem, the copy constructor how do I? Think about overwriting the constructor but it did not work for me

Comment: @AndrewS
This you say is true but they ask me that way, but what you say is true. I do not know how to copy the constructor, I thought I would overwrite it but it does not work

Comment: All you need to do is supply an additional constructor in User. Declare it with taking a User object as a parameter. Then, in the constructor's body, call `this(user.getUserName(), user.getPassword(), user.getFullName());`

Comment: Thank you! @Jacob I did the following and perfect        public User(User Prueba){
     this(Prueba.getUserName(),Prueba.getPassword(),Prueba.getFullName());
 
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
 public User(User Prueba){
 this(Prueba.getUserName(),Prueba.getPassword(),Prueba.getFullName());

}
```

Thanks to the answers they gave me.
Without you it would be more difficult